# How to store JSON response in variable in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, openweathermap

I am struggling to get response from API and save it in variable to use it further in Node.js. Maybe I don't know how the language works. Here is the problem:

```
// Objective, get current temperature of New Delhi in celcius

var request = require('request');

var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1261481&appid=#####&units=metric";

request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    curTemp = JSON.parse(body).main.temp;  // curTemp holds the value we want
  }
})

// but I want to use it here
console.log(curTemp);
```

I want to store JSON response from openweathermap (i.e. `body.main.temp`) to a variable. Then I'll be composing a tweet out of current temperature.

Comment: Perhaps you can tweet inside the callback ?

Comment: A common async problem, when you try to print the `curTemp` the variable is most likely undefined as the HTTP request isn't finished yet. So use callbacks or promises or wrap the code that depends on the `curtemp` into the same scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Node.js, it's all about callback (or functions you need to call later).
So all you need to is create is a tweet function and call it when you got your data!

```
var request = require('request');
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id=1261481& appid=#####&units=metric";
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    curTemp = JSON.parse(body).main.temp;  // curTemp holds the value we want
    tweet(curTemp)
  }
})

// but I want to use it here
function tweet(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

Consider this is not a good approach for coding in async.

Comment: lol.. was it this simple?

Comment: haha .. i just about  to show u how u should think in nodejs.

Answer (score 0):

request is asynchronous. If you want to write asynchronous code in this way, you should use an API that returns a Promise, e.g. [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios). You can then use [async/await](https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await) to write your code.

Comment: Can you explain with code please? I'm completely new to node.

Comment: @SantoshKumar thats not a node thing. you may want to learn more about javascript itself beforehand. start learning about promises and asyncronous stuff on mozilla's developer network.

Comment: Please do not answer dupes. Flag for closure instead.